Interacting with inherited functions using ethers
I have two contracts.
contract Core is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    uint256 price;
    constructor() ERC721("NFT", "NFT1") Ownable(msg.sender) {
      
    }
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
       return price;
    }
}

Contract Extended is Core {
   constructor(uint256 _price) Core(){
      price = _price;
   }
}

I am building a nextjs app and want to interact with the contracts to get the ticket price. I deploy the Extended contract and get the contract address and ABI and use them in my nextjs app like so:
export const ContractAddress: string = '0xAddressOfDeployedExtendedContract';

export const ContractAbi: Array<string> = [
  'function getPrice() public view returns (uint256)'
];

This is my js for calling the contract:
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(walletProvider);
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
const contract = new Contract(ContractAddress, ContractAbi, signer);
const currentPrice = await contract.getPrice();

But I keep getting an error like the getPrice function does not exist. "Internal JSON-RPC error" is the message.
If I deploy the Core contract separately this works (makes sense I guess)
How can I interact with inherited functions in ethers? What am I missing?
Thank you

Can you try using the full ABI of the Extended contract?

What do you mean?

Means, if you can copy the full ABI of the Extended contract and use the same, instead of just using the ABI portion for the getPrice function.

I did use the full ABI but still doesn't work. Also I cannot call functions like ownerOf from the ERC contract even when I declare them in the ABI.

You're using the function representation of getPrice, instead you've to use the ABI representation (i.e., in JSON format) of the function, like:
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

Then, it would work fine:
const contractAddress = "0xAddressOfDeployedExtendedContract";

const targetedABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
]

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, targetedABI, provider);

const currentPrice = await contract.getPrice();

console.log(currentPrice);

If you want to call various functions of the contract, then you can use the full ABI, that would look like:
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_price",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721IncorrectOwner",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InsufficientApproval",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "approver",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InvalidApprover",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InvalidOperator",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InvalidOwner",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "receiver",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InvalidReceiver",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721InvalidSender",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ERC721NonexistentToken",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnableInvalidOwner",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "account",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnableUnauthorizedAccount",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ApprovalForAll",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_fromTokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_toTokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "BatchMetadataUpdate",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "MetadataUpdate",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "previousOwner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "renounceOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "data",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setApprovalForAll",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getApproved",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "isApprovedForAll",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ownerOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes4",
                "name": "interfaceId",
                "type": "bytes4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "supportsInterface",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenURI",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]


If you're using Remix IDE, then you can copy the ABI by going to the Solidity compiler in the side menu:

If you're using Hardhat, then you can get the ABI from the artifacts/contracts folder:

